download official .ova images for ubuntu 24.04 for olvm
Are there any official .ova images for Ubuntu 24.04 for import into OLVM (Oracle Linux Virtualization Manager)?

Ubuntu provides cloud images in OVA form (VirtualBox/VMware) but I don't know if those cloud images are complete on their own, from my knowledge they're a base image but still require some bootstrapping to set up.  They're also not full VM images that'd work out of the box.  Ubuntu outside of their Cloud offerings doesn't really provide VM images of full systems - you're better off building a VM in VirtualBox or such yourself and then importing it onto Oracle, or mounting the ISO in a new VM in Oracle yourself and installing direct-to-VM from the ISOs.
